# Bash is adding single quotes when resolving variable

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do mongo export with query and I'm trying to create script which is failing for not so sure reasons:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "$(date) Preparing env variables"
Environment=$1
Days=$2
queryStr=''
if [ -n "$Days" ]; then
    dateTimeStamp=`date +%s`
    dateTimeStamp=$(((dateTimeStamp-$Days*86400) * 1000))
    queryStr+="--query='{ _updatedAt: { \$gt: $dateTimeStamp } }'"
fi
set -x
mongoexport $queryStr
set +x
```

And when executed I get this weird single quotes that are added when my command executes:

```
+ mongoexport '--query='\''{' _updatedAt: '{' '$gt:' 1641905572000 '}' '}'\'''
```

Comment: [BashFAQ/050 - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: thanks, always problems with bash....

Comment: Don’t use it then. Or if you do, use [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: Is there any other language, in which you craft code by concatenating strings? Maybe SQL, if you like SQL injections. Never do this: neither in any other language nor in Bash.

Comment: These single quotes are just a side-effect of using `set -x`. They're not literally in the variable's value, they just indicate to the human where the words are. You'd see similar effects with `printf '%q\n' "$queryStr"` or `echo "${queryStr@Q}"`

Comment: FYI with bash v5, there's a builtin variable that holds the `date +%s` value: `$EPOCHSECONDS`. `dateTimeStamp=(( (EPOCHSECONDS - Days * 86400) * 1000))`

Comment: FYI2: not every day of the year has 86400 seconds

Comment: @glennjackman not all days have 24hrs